# Getting a Facebook page access token for a simple app (Python)

Tags: python, facebook

I'm trying to create a very simple Facebook app (using the Python SDK) that does nothing more than post to its own page. The eventual app will make one post per day, and that's all it will do. (Please note that I am a novice programmer, and this is in part a learning exercise for me.)

My initial test code looks like this, and it successfully posts to the page:

```
import facebook

token = 'XXXXX'

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token = token,
                          version = "2.1")

graph.put_object(parent_object='me', 
                 connection_name='feed',
                 message='Test post to page')
```

The catch is that it only works if I plug in a value for `token` that is a valid page access token. For testing, I can get one from the Graph API Explorer, but obviously I'd like my app to be able to get one each time it runs, using its own credentials (e.g. app ID and app secret).

I have been searching for a way to do this with the Python SDK, but I have had no luck finding out how, in part because most apps are much more complicated (involving user logins and so forth). I don't see Is there a simple way to do this, or is the problem more complicated than I think it is?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to auto-generate a Page Token, but you can use an Extended Page Token - it is valid forever.

More information:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Token debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: Thanks! I still find it all quite confusing, but I think I eventually put all the steps together and got back a token that didn't appear to have any expiration date. I guess I'll find out if it ever expires!

Comment: you can debug the token here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/